# java serialize a custom linked list

Tags: java, serialization

I didn't want to use the provided LinkedList Class so I made up a custom linked list. the problem is that i am worried of stack overflow problems that may occur when I serialize this object with the default read/write object fucntions

I saw from another SO post that you have to use custom serialization like below :

```
MyClass{

    transient Node header; 

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next)
        out.writeObject(e.element);
    }
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
    }



}
```

this is the node class

```
Node{
    transient Node next;
    transient Node prev;
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next)
        out.writeObject(e.element);
    }
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
    }

}
```

How ever I am wondering, because I made the header field transient, when i read the class wouldn't it be null? how do I make it refer to the header node...

same for the nodes , since next and prev fields are transient when I read the object the fields would be null how do I make them maintain the references to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, they will be null.

You have to implement readObject in similar fashion you implemented write object:

```
while(elementsToRead()); // you need to know somehow how long you need to read
{
    add(inputStream.readObject());
}
```

I would suggest looking into implementations of read and write objects for lists in Java library.

Why you cannot use Java linked list? If something is missing, has you considered extending linkedLlist?

You can basically look into Linked List source code and see how the serialization is performed.